# How can I save Spark Dataframe into a partitioned Cassandra table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a partitioned Cassandra table :

```
sess.execute(s"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.details(
                         | userId text,
                         | name text,
                         | age text,
                         | date date,
                         | PRIMARY KEY (date))
                         | WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)""".stripMargin)
```

I am using Scala 2.11.8 and Spark 2.0 and Cassandra. Here the table is partitioned by 'date' col. So in this case, how can I save my data frame into this table? Is there a Scala code example with the APIs I need to use? Without the partition and clustering I am using :

```
myDF.distinct().write
    .cassandraFormat(keyspace = "test", table = "details", cluster="cluster")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()
```

This should be saved every micro batch in a streaming application, in case that matters for choosing a performance-oriented API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Spark Cassandra Connector is automatically partitioning and batching. There is nothing you as the end user have to do. See

[Basic overview of how writes happen](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/how-spark-cassandra-connector-writes-data)

Or for more details
[This tuning overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKIHRD6kUOc)